# Will a Kozak sequence within a coding sequence interfere with eukaryotic expression?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics

I want to make a DNA vaccine for fish by using plasmid pcDNA3.1(+) with a bacterial antigen. Unfortunately, there is a Kozak sequence in the middle of my target gene.

I am concerned that this Kozak sequence will interfere with translation inside fish cells.

Can I still use this gene of interest to make a DNA vaccine?
Is there any way to deal with this unwanted Kozak sequence?

Comment: You could always try codon editing to interrupt the Kozak sequence, yet still have the same protein sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much @MattDMo, such a good idea to try :))

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site — in particular focus on how to [ask] questions effectively on this site. Please also ensure your future posts are [formatted correctly](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) — writing clearly is an essential part of scientific communication. ——— I have edited your post extensively — I hope that this has preserved the essence of your question. Please check and [edit] to correct any errors I may have introduced.